# How to codeigniter Sending Parameters Between Controller and View different function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new codeigniter developer.
I trying sending controller between views but only index function sending.
When I try different function, I get this error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: sample

Filename: views/merhaba_sayfasi.php

Line Number: 8
```

My controller file = merhaba.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Merhaba extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $data["title"]="İlk codeigniter sayfam";
            $data["giris_baslik"] = "Merhaba Dünya";
            $this->load->view('merhaba_sayfasi',$data);
        }

        public function example(){
            $data["sample"] = "Sample php";
            $this->load->view("merhaba_sayfasi",$data);
        }
    }
?>
```

My view file = merhaba_sayfasi.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3><?php echo $giris_baslik; ?></h3>
<?php echo $sample; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

My explorer image

http://www.medyasef.com/questions/codeigniter_function_error.png

Answer (score 0):

It depends what URL you are calling?

If you call "/app/Merhaba" or "/app/Merhaba/index" you will not see the sample variable.

If you call "/app/Merhaba/example" then you should see it. It all depends what function of the controller you are calling - by default its only the index function

Comment: First thanx your answer. Your answer true but There is a problem. When I calling localhost:8888/ci/index.php/merhaba/ I not see sample variable but When I Call localhost:8888/ci/index.php/merhaba/example I not see $giris_baslik variable and I get error. http://www.medyasef.com/questions/ci_sample_error.png

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to display a variable, whose value hasn't been set, that's why the error is being thrown.

You could check in your view to ensure that a variable has a value before attempting to echo it.

So, instead of:

```
<?php echo $sample; ?>
```

You could use:

```
<?php if(isset($sample)) {echo $sample;} ?>
```

---

Although, I'd recommending keeping the logic in your controller and setting all of the values in your controller before loading the view

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want see all php varibles.

Comment: Then you have to pass all of the variables to the view in the same function.